# Is there a way to root a Samsung Galaxy S4 running LineageOS 17.1?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4, rom, lineageos, magisk

Following the "[Samsung (System-as-root)](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root)"* instructions, I cannot get Magisk to patch [lineage-17.1-20210304-nightly-jfltexx-signed.zip](https://download.lineageos.org/jfltexx) for a [Samsung Galaxy S4 (SGH-M919)](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/jfltexx). Magisk throws an "unsupported/unknown image format" error.

<sup>*since Magik says SAR=yes</sup>

Is there a way to root a Samsung Galaxy S4 running LineageOS 17.1?

<sup>cf. ["root on 17.1?" r/LineageOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/i0paur/root_on_171/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a Magisk 22.0 bug ([issue #3949](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/3949)).

Rebooting into download mode (<kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>) and running

> [heimdall](https://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/) flash --RECOVERY [Magisk-v21.4.zip](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/tag/v21.4)

rooted it!

Comment: I wasn't even aware Magisk could patch LineageOS zips! Usually I extract the boot partition image (from recovery), patch it from Magisk, and re-flash it.